# Кастомизация фильтра в Sonata Admin

Tags: php, symfony2, sonata

Имеется фильтр в админке сайта, какие атрибуты нужно использовать для изменения [лейблов](https://prnt.sc/i8olvv) на значения из словаря?

P.s. В документации ответ не нашёл

```html
$datagrid->add('creationDate', 'doctrine_orm_date_range',  array('label'  => 'list.creationDate'), null, array())
```

Answer (score 1):

В [примере в документации](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/3-x/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html#example), атрибуты передают в пятом параметре. Попробуйте так:

```
$datagrid->add('creationDate', 'doctrine_orm_date_range',  array(), null, array('label'  => 'list.creationDate'))
```

Comment: ссылка на пример не помешала бы

Comment: коллега, я перенёс ссылку из комментариев в ответ. рекомендую и вам придерживаться аналогичного подхода. А ваш комментарий (как и мои) уже становятся неактуальными и как вы прочитаете - можете удалить свои, а я свой.